# Button is not wokring in spring

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, jsp, button

In jsp file, in javascript

```
<c:set var="like" value="${like}"/>
<c:set var="unlike" value="${unlike}"/>
<script src="resources/js/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var like=${like};
var unlike=${unlike};
var no=${vdto.no}
/* like & unlike */
$(function(){
if(like==0||like==null){
$("#like").hide();
$("#like_disabled").show();
}   
else{   
$("#like_disabled").hide();
$("#like").show();
}

if(unlike==0||like==null){
$("#unlike").hide();}
else{   
$("#unlike_disabled").hide();
}   
});
function like()
{like--;location.href="tftube_videoView?no="+no+"&like="+like;}
function like_disabled()
{like++;location.href="tftube_videoView?no="+no+"&like="+like;}

function unlike(){unlike--;location.href="tftube_videoView?                
no="+no+"&unlike="+unlike;}
function unlike_disabled(){unlike++;location.href="tftube_videoView?
no="+no+"&unlike="+unlike;}
```

In the jsp file, in jsp code

```
<button id="like_disabled" onclick="like_disabled()">like</button>
<button id="like" onclick="like()" >like</button><!-- it's not work -->
<button id="unlike_disabled" onclick="unlike_disabled()"         
value="unlike">unlike</button>
<button id="unlike" onclick="unlike()" >unlike</button>
```

In controller

```
//request
@RequestMapping(value="/tftube_videoView", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView tftube_videoView(HttpServletRequest arg0, 
                            HttpServletResponse arg1) throws Exception {
    ModelAndView mv=new ModelAndView();
    HttpSession session=arg0.getSession();

    String no_raw=arg0.getParameter("no");//number of video
    int no=0;
    if(no_raw!=null){
    no=Integer.parseInt(no_raw);}//tftube_video

    VideoDTO vdto=videoDAO.getVideo(no);//a video's total information

    String video_name=vdto.getVideo_name();

    String like_stat_raw=arg0.getParameter("like");
    String unlike_stat_raw=arg0.getParameter("unlike");


    System.out.println("request like:"+like_stat_raw);
    System.out.println("request unlike:"+unlike_stat_raw);

    int res_like=0;
    int res_unlike=0;
    /*VideoDTO likedto=new VideoDTO();*/
    if(like_stat_raw!=null){
        int like_stat=Integer.parseInt(like_stat_raw);
        System.out.println("들어온 like 숫자 변환"+like_stat);
            switch(like_stat){
            /*case 1:res_like=videoDAO.click_like(no);break;*/
            case 0:res_like=videoDAO.cancel_like(no);break;
            default:res_like=videoDAO.click_like(no);break;
            }
    }

    if(unlike_stat_raw!=null){
        int unlike_stat=Integer.parseInt(unlike_stat_raw);          
        switch(unlike_stat){
        /*case 1:res_unlike=videoDAO.click_unlike(1);break;*/
        case 0:res_unlike=videoDAO.cancel_unlike(0);break;
        default:res_like=videoDAO.click_like(no);break;
        }           
    }
    //response
            int like_status=videoDAO.getVideo(no).getLike_status();
            int unlike_status=videoDAO.getVideo(no).getUnlike_status();
            System.out.println("response like:"+like_status);
            System.out.println("response unlike:"+unlike_status);
            mv.addObject("like",like_status);
            mv.addObject("unlike",unlike_status);       
            //end of response
```

The rest is omitted.

At first, there are two boxes in the result (button 'like' and 'unlike' are hide)
If I click button 'id=like_disabled', its events will operate and it will hide and button 'id=like' will show.
It's not problem, so far, but if I click button 'id=like', it's not working.
Why?? and teach me solution please.

Comment: Did you check the browser's console if there are any errors?

Comment: Because it's not work, it doesn't occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are using the same name - `like` - for a variable and for a method. That is totally a bad practice.

You are declaring `like` as a variable first and then as a method. When `like_disabled` is called you are doing `like--` and, from that moment on, `like` is not longer a method. I think you should get a `TypeError` on the console.

So, stop using same name for vars and methods.